# Can't add executable

Tags: bash, macos, asdf-vm

What I'm trying to do:

```
# OR for Max OSX
echo '. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo '. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I did it, then:

```
MBP-slava:~ slava$ asdf plugin-list
-bash: asdf: command not found
```

Then I did this:

```
cd $HOME
touch .bash_profile
vim .bash_profile

#.bash_profile

. slava/.asdf/asdf.sh
. slava/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
.
.
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~                                                                                                                                                                                                           
~
```

I try to:

```
. .bash_profile
```

Which outputs:

```
-bash: slava/.asdf/asdf.sh: No such file or directory
-bash: slava/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash: No such file or directory
-bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
-bash: .: filename argument required
.: usage: . filename [arguments]
```

And then:

```
MBP-slava:~ slava$ asdf plugin-list
-bash: asdf: command not found
```

OS X El Capitan

Library: https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf

Answer (score 0):

If your motive is to add the path to the executable `asdf.sh`
to `PATH` environment variable, then do

```
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.asdf/"
echo "$PATH">>~/.bash_profile
```

Start a new terminal session - for the new .bash_profile - to be in effect, and run the command like

```
asdf.sh # Autocomplete should work for this
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup instructions are incorrect - the Homebrew formula installs things a bit differently. The paths (in case of Bash) are:

```
. /usr/local/opt/asdf/asdf.sh
. /usr/local/opt/asdf/etc/bash_completion.d/asdf.bash
```

Comment: How do you know they are using Homebrew?